# Custom priors in PyMC

Tags: python, statsmodels, pymc

Say I want to put a custom prior on two variables `a` and `b` in PyMC, e.g.:

`p(a,b)∝(a+b)^(−5/2)`

(for the motivation behind this choice of prior, see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94310/2798))

Can this be done in PyMC? If so how?

As an example, I would like to define such prior on `a` and `b` in the model below.

```
import pymc as pm

# ...
# Code that defines the prior: p(a,b)∝(a+b)^(−5/2)
# ...

theta   = pm.Beta("prior", alpha=a, beta=b)

# Binomials that share a common prior
bins = dict()
for i in xrange(N_cities):
    bins[i] = pm.Binomial('bin_{}'.format(i), p=theta,n=N_trials[i],  value=N_yes[i], observed=True)

mcmc = pm.MCMC([bins, ps])
```

## Update

Following John Salvatier's advice, I try the following (note that I am in PyMC2, although I would be happy to switch to PyMC3), but my questions are:

1. What should I import so that I can properly inherit from `Continuous`?
2. In PyMC2, do I still need to stick to Theano notation?
3. Finally, how can I later tell my `Beta` distribution that `alpha` and `beta` have a prior from this multivariate distribution?

   import pymc.Multivariate.Continuous

   class CustomPrior(Continuous):
       """
       p(a,b)∝(a+b)^(−5/2)

   ```
   :Parameters:
       None

   :Support:
       2 positive floats (parameters to a Beta distribution)
   """
   def __init__(self, mu, tau, *args, **kwargs):
       super(CustomPrior, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   def logp(self, a,b):


       return np.log(math.power(a+b),-5./2)
   ```

Comment: oh sorry, I thought you were in PyMC3 for some reason. You can do this in pymc2 but its different. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PyMC2, the trick is to put the `a` and `b` parameters together:

```
# Code that defines the prior: p(a,b)∝(a+b)^(−5/2)
@pm.stochastic
def ab(power=-2.5, value=[1,1]):
    if np.any(value <= 0):
        return -np.Inf
    return power * np.log(value[0]+value[1])

a = ab[0]
b = ab[1]
```

[This notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/11238257) has a full example.

Comment: Thanks!  This is **exactly** what I was looking for. I have been looking for an answer to this question for a long time. Do you happen to know, by the way, how to do this in PyMC3?

Comment: You are welcome.  I've updated this with a bug fix (return log-probability) and the beginnings of a PyMC3 version.

Answer (score 4):

Yup! It's quite possible, and in fact quite straightforward.

If you're in PyMC 2, check out the [documentation on the creation of stochastic variables](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html#creation-of-stochastic-variables).

```
@pymc.stochastic(dtype=int)
def switchpoint(value=1900, t_l=1851, t_h=1962):
    """The switchpoint for the rate of disaster occurrence."""
    if value > t_h or value < t_l:
        # Invalid values
        return -np.inf
    else:
        # Uniform log-likelihood
        return -np.log(t_h - t_l + 1)
```

If you're in PyMC 3, have a look at [multivariate.py](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/master/pymc/distributions/multivariate.py).  Keep in mind the values passed in to **init** and logp are all theano variables, not numpy arrays. Is that enough to get you started?

For example, this is the Multivariate Normal distribution

```
class MvNormal(Continuous):
    """
    Multivariate normal

    :Parameters:
        mu : vector of means
        tau : precision matrix

    .. math::
        f(x \mid \pi, T) = \frac{|T|^{1/2}}{(2\pi)^{1/2}} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu)^{\prime}T(x-\mu) \right\}

    :Support:
        2 array of floats
    """
    def __init__(self, mu, tau, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MvNormal, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mean = self.median = self.mode = self.mu = mu
        self.tau = tau

    def logp(self, value):
        mu = self.mu
        tau = self.tau

        delta = value - mu
        k = tau.shape[0]

        return 1/2. * (-k * log(2*pi) + log(det(tau)) - dot(delta.T, dot(tau, delta)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @John. I think I understand the definition above, but I am trying to follow the steps without success. I have updated the OP with more specific questions.

Comment: Thank you @John. This is very helpful. The only remaining question is how I can use the multivariate prior to get the prior on the individual variables (e.g. `alpha` and `beta` in a Binomial distribution, as in the code in the OP). How do I get the prior on the individual variables from the multivariate prior?

Comment: Oh, like you want a multivariate prior on variables with different names? I don't think there's a way to do that. You can make a multivariate variable and index into it to get the components separately and then name them. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks @John. In the code example that I have at the top of my OP, I define `theta   = pm.Beta("prior", alpha=a, beta=b)`. What I want to do is define my prior on `a` and `b` as `p(a,b)∝(a+b)^(−5/2)`. It looks like I can define `p(a,b)` in PyMC2 with `@pymc.stochastic` as you mentioned in your answer. What I would later need to pass `a` and `b` to the Beta call above. This is the part that I don't know how to do.