# How to define a custom prior in PyMC3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I would like to know if it is possible to define a custom prior in PyMC3 (and how to do it).  From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198247/custom-priors-in-pymc) it seems that in PyMC2 is relatively easy to do (without the need to modified the source code), but in PyMC3 is not that easy (or I am not understanding something).
I am trying to replicate a prior from the book "Doing Bayesian Data Analysis", that is implemented in BUGS:

```
model {
# Likelihood. Each flip is Bernoulli.
for ( i in 1 : N1 ) { y1[i]  ̃ dbern( theta1 ) }
for ( i in 1 : N2 ) { y2[i]  ̃ dbern( theta2 ) }
# Prior. Curved scallo not ps!
x  ̃ dunif(0,1)
y  ̃ dunif(0,1)
N <- 4
xt <- sin( 2*3.141593*N * x ) / (2*3.141593*N) + x
yt <- 3 * y + (1/3)
xtt <- pow( xt , yt )
theta1 <- xtt
theta2 <- y
}
```

The prior does not make too much sense, it just an example of how to define a custom prior and the versatility of BUGS.

My attempt to implement the above custom prior is:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
from pymc import Continuous
from theano.tensor import sin, log

# Generate the data
y1 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])  # 5 heads and 2 tails
y2 = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])  # 2 heads and 5 tails

class Custom_prior(Continuous): 
"""
custom prior
"""
    def __init__(self, y, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Custom_prior, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.y = y
        self.N = 4
        self.mean = 0.625  # FIXME
    def logp(self, value):
        N = self.N
        y = self.y
        return -log((sin(2*3.141593*N * value)
                     / (2*3.141593*N) + value)**(3 * y + (1/3)))

with pm.Model() as model:
    theta2 = pm.Uniform('theta2', 0, 1)  # prior
    theta1 = Custom_prior('theta1', theta2)  # prior
    # define the likelihood
    y1 = pm.Bernoulli('y1', p=theta1, observed=y1)
    y2 = pm.Bernoulli('y2', p=theta2, observed=y2)
    # Generate a MCMC chain
    start = pm.find_MAP()  # Find starting value by optimization
    trace = pm.sample(5000, pm.NUTS(), progressbar=False)
```

EDIT

Following the answer of [chris-fonnesbeck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24739407/815542)

I think I need something like:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    theta2 = pm.Uniform('theta2', 0, 1)  # prior
    N = 4
    theta1 = pm.DensityDist('theta1', lambda value: -log((sin(2*3.141593*N * value)
                       / (2*3.141593*N) + value)**(3 * theta2 + (1/3))))
    # define the likelihood
    y1 = pm.Bernoulli('y1', p=theta1, observed=y1)
    y2 = pm.Bernoulli('y2', p=theta2, observed=y2)

    # Generate a MCMC chain
    start = pm.find_MAP()  # Find starting value by optimization
    trace = pm.sample(10000, pm.NUTS(), progressbar=False) # Use NUTS sampling
```

The only problem is that I get the same value for all the posterior samples of theta1 and theta2, I guess there is some problem with my custom prior or the combination of priors and likelihoods. A successful definition of a custom prior can be found in this [example](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/master/pymc/examples/custom_dists.py)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you post the full BUGS model? In the above, it just looks like a series of deterministic transformations in BUGS after the priors for x and y, rather than the definition of a prior.

Assuming the `logp` above is what you want, though, you can implement it in PyMC much more simply as:

```
def logp(value, y):
    N  = 4
    return -log((sin(2*3.141593*N * value)
                 / (2*3.141593*N) + value)**(3 * y + (1/3)))

theta1 = pm.DensityDist('theta1', logp, value, y=theta2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edit my question to add the full model. Anyway as stated in the book, the prior is not a "real" prior one would use in research is just and example that a prior could be anything and not necessary well-know distribution like Beta, Gaussian, etc.